# ensure that android layout content stays within screen bounds

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have been given a screen comp from my UI designer that has a nav bar at the top, then 5 icons with matching text labels underneath each one. I need to make sure that the padding for each of them stays relative enough that all 5 of the icon/label pairs stay on the screen.

Here is the reference guide I have been given: [image]

Here is my current XML - two simple relative layouts - one for the Nav Bar, and one for the remaining space, with aligned and padded content (and one background image that they both sit on top of).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/guide_bg_img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/guide_bg" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/guide_nav"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@+color/transparent_grey"
        android:padding="5dp" 
    >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/guide_toggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/guide_replay"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/guide_toggle_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/guide_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/guide_back_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/guide_replay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/guide_toggle"
            android:src="@drawable/guide_replay_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/guide_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/guide_replay"
            android:text="@+string/label_guide"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/guide_labels"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/guide_nav"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/guide_ear_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/guide_ear_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/guide_ear_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/guide_ear_icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/label_guide_ear"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/guide_car_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/guide_ear_label"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/guide_cars_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/guide_car_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/guide_car_icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/label_guide_car"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/guide_live_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/guide_car_label"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/guide_live_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/guide_live_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/guide_live_icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/label_guide_live"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/guide_device_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/guide_live_label"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/guide_device_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/guide_device_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/guide_device_icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/label_guide_device"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/guide_explore_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/guide_device_label"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/guide_explore_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/guide_explore_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/guide_explore_icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/label_guide_explore"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/guide_explore_enjoy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/guide_explore_label"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/label_guide_enjoy"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The issue is that my bottom two TextViews are disappearing off of the bottom of the screen.

See attached image:

[image]

Part of my problem is that I have only (currently) been given one density of assets, but I am testing on four live devices as well as several emulators (N5, N4, Galaxy Nexus, HTC One X), and the problem is persisting across screen sizes and densities.

I can attempt to hardcode paddings in order to massage this, but I want to believe that there is a better way to do this - basically to scale the content of a layout to the bounds that is is set to.

I have searched the net and SO, and maybe my terminology is failing me, but I am not finding the results that I am looking for... 
Does that make sense, and is there any thoughts ?

Comment: You can use linear layout and can give weight to it, although its not good practice.

Comment: @sandycan you give an example? and explain why its not good practice ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a vertical LinearLayout and weight each item in it 1 as below:

```
<Linearlayout android:orientation="vertical" ...>
    <ImageButton android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="0dip" .../>
    <ImageButton android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="0dip" .../>
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ok... will explore that - thx. can you explain how that works & why ?